# getting sysdate on entering a value in another feild in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working in oracle apex master detail form. I have a table named detail on which this form is created. I want to update the value of time_stamp by sysdate as soon as I enter a value in status.
kindly guide me how can i do this?
my table is:

````
DID number(10,0),
status char(1),
time_stamp timestamp);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem  a while ago. As per my understanding, there are two approaches.

1) Instead of creating a form on a table, create separate fields for each form field in apex, and let the user input data there. And then create a procedure to update the data on submit.

2) You can create a trigger on detail table as described below

```
create or replace trigger detail_update_trig
     before update or insert
     on detail
     FOR EACH ROW
declare
begin
    :new.timestamp:=sysdate;
end;
/
```

Although there might be a better approaches for the problem, but this is how it worked for me.

Hope this would solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks Arif . if I put a checkbox on status column and as soon as I click on checkbox it changes the timestamp value to sysdate. Can you tell me how can I do this in apex forms?

Comment: You want to update timestamp on front end (Apex). Right ?
I am a little confused here.

Comment: Could you not create a Dynamic Action tied to the checkbox so that when the box is checked then you can populate the field with the desired value?

Comment: Yes Arif.....I want to update time stamp on front end right after clicking the checkbox of that particular row

Comment: I tried, doing that, but couldn't reach anywhere. Also, I might be wrong, but I noticed that in master detail form, it is not possible to update the child table. Although you can add data(insert row), but not update already existing ones in child. Checkbox present there are to select the rows you want to delete. But you can update the parent table data by using the trigger solution I provided above. And for the case of child table, you can set default value of `time_stamp` column to `sysdate` and setting the field type to text field and readonly always. So when you insert, latest date present.